# How to return a database resultset from a java web service

Tags: java

I am new to java web services. I am fetching records from a database and need to return my resultset from the web service. From what I have read, resultset is a interface so it cannot be used as a return type. I know that dotnet web services have a `DataSet` type used to return database records. Is there anything similar in java? If not, can anyone suggest what I should use instead of the resultset?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use a web service then do **not** use a `ResultSet` or any other `Java` *specific* construct e.g. `ArrayList` etc.
Just return an array of `Records` to the client where each array entry is a custom (`JAXB`) class `Record` which represents an entry/row in the database.
Just populate the array in your server with the result of the database query and return that array as a result to your clients

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer... so there is no option to use like dotnet dataset?

Comment: I don't know `.NET`.But in web services you should avoid any implementation language specific constructs in order to achieve `interoperability` which is the main reason to use a web service in the first place